# TypeError: res.end is not a function. In passport npm package

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, authentication, passport.js

this is the error. I am stuck in it. have a look at this..

```
TypeError: res.end is not a function
    at allFailed (C:\Users\sam\OneDrive\desktop\WebDevPractice\secret-files\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:174:11)
    at attempt (C:\Users\sam\OneDrive\desktop\WebDevPractice\secret-files\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:180:28)
    at Strategy.strategy.fail (C:\Users\sam\OneDrive\desktop\WebDevPractice\secret-files\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:302:9)
    at Strategy.authenticate (C:\Users\sam\OneDrive\desktop\WebDevPractice\secret-files\node_modules\passport-local\lib\strategy.js:75:17)
    at attempt (C:\Users\sam\OneDrive\desktop\WebDevPractice\secret-files\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:366:16)
    at authenticate (C:\Users\sam\OneDrive\desktop\WebDevPractice\secret-files\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:367:7)
    at C:\Users\sam\OneDrive\desktop\WebDevPractice\secret-files\app.js:70:37
    at C:\Users\sam\OneDrive\desktop\WebDevPractice\secret-files\node_modules\passport-local-mongoose\index.js:247:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

// kindly look at the register route.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require ("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(session({
    secret : "thisIsMyLitlleSecret",
    resave : false,
    saveUninitialized : false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

console.log(process.env.API_KEY);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB" , { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true });
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email : String,
    password : String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = mongoose.model("User",userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());
 
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.render("home");
});

app.get("/login", function(req,res){
    res.render("login");
});

app.get("/secrets", function(req,res){
    if(req.isAauthenticated){
        res.render("secrets");
    }
    else{
        res.redirect("/login")
    }
})
app.get("/register", function(req,res){
    res.render("register");
});

app.post("/register", function(req,res){

  User.register({username : req.body.username}, req.body.password, function(err, user){
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
          res.redirect("/register");
      }
      else
      passport.authenticate("local")(res,req,function(){
          res.redirect("/secrets");
      });
  });

});



app.post("/login",function(req,res){

});

app.listen(3000,function(req,res){
    console.log("Server running on port 3000!!");
});
```

//this is the register ejs page

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <h1>Register</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">

          <!-- Makes POST request to /register route -->
          <form action="/register" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Register</button>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card social-block">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a class="btn btn-block" href="/auth/google" role="button">
            <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
            Sign Up with Google
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> -->

  </div>
</div>

<%- include('partials/header') %>
```

how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a little typo mistake, in your code "req" has to be before "res", here is your code:

```
 passport.authenticate("local")(res,req,function(){
          res.redirect("/secrets");
      });
```

Simply swap places of your request and response, should be - (req, res), then it will work. Here is what it should be, looks similar, hard to spot the difference:

```
 passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
          res.redirect("/secrets");
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually passport is middleware.

```
app.post(‘/register’, passport.authenticate(‘local’), (req, res) => {
// 
}
```

Also why is it on the register route not login?